# Printing 2d Array Elements with Printf

Tags: c, arrays, printf

These lines all print the correct entry out of the array, but each only prints 3 characters of each element instead of the 4 characters that define each element. Is there a default setting or settings for Printf that I should be using or changing?

```
    printf("at time[0][0]: \n%s \n",&time[0][0]);
    printf("at time[3][0]: \n%s \n",&time[3][0]);
    printf("at time[5][0]: \n%s \n",&time[5][0]);
```

Comment: Show the definition of `time` and what you think its value is at print time.

Comment: `%s` is for printing a *string* (which is a series of `char` followed by a null terminator). You didn't post enough code for anyone to check if `time[n]` actually contains strings.

Comment: it all depends on what is in time[][], show declaration and how you fill it to be able to answer your question.

Comment: So, what is the problem? I re-read your question several times, but I don't see any explanation of what the problem is and why it is a problem. I vaguely suspect that "3 characters" is apparently wrong. But you never said how many characters you expected to see printed and why it shouldn't be 3.

Comment: Mark, before attempting to reopen your question you should read the comments and implement their suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%s is the format specifier for a null terminated character array. So, in your case, if time is declared as time[][] (two dimensional array), then time[0], time[3], time[5] are individual null terminated character array,. time[0][0] means only one character then (first one in the buffer). And &time[0][0] means same as time[0]. Check if you have time[0][3] as 0 or '\0' by chance or check whether the buffers are null terminated, if not, do so.

Comment: The buffers were not null terminated, and the entries were 4 characters, so printf was backing off one character from the end of the entry. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use %c format specifier to print that...
Remove & from printf...
If you want to print the whole row of the array use only row index...

Comment: This is over-emphatic given the lack of information in the question.  Given `char time[6][20];` suitably initialized, it is perfectly legitimate to use the `printf()` statements shown in the question.  The problem is: we don't know how the time array is defined.